# How to pass function to V-on

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm stuck with this error when I try to press Next to switch question & answer.
I'm currently using Vue2.
What should I change if i want to use nextbtn function to switch question & answer at the same time.
Error:"[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: 'ReferenceError: nextBtn is not defined'

found in

---> 
"

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app1">
  <display-question></display-question>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
Vue.component('display-question',{
  data: function(){
    return{
      counter: 0,
      currentQuestion: 0,
      answered: 0,
      showWrongQuestion: false,
      wrongQuestions: [],
      temp: [],
      wrongAnswers: 0,
      correctAnswers: 0,
    message: "Enter your answer here",
    WhatAnswer: "default",
   questions: [
            {
            question: 'What is the capital of Ukrain ?',
            answer: [
                'Kyiv',
                '   Kabul',
                '   Buenos Aires',
                '   Praia'
            ],
            correct_answer: 0,
            selected: null,
            sense: 0
            },
            {
            question: 'When was Queen Elizabeth II death ?',
            answer: [
                '11/09/2022',
                '08/09/2022',
                '12/08/2022',
                '07/09/2022'
            ],
            correct_answer: 1,
            selected: null,
            sense: 0
            },
         {
            question: 'How many bones are there in human body?',
            answer: [
                '206',
                '186',
                '209',
                '190'
            ],
            correct_answer: 0,
            selected: null,
            sense: 0
            },
         {
            question: 'Who were the 30th president of ?',
            answer: [
                'Julia Eileen Gillard',
                'John Winston Howard ',
                ' Scott John Morrison ',
                'Anthony Albanese,'
            ],
            correct_answer: 2,
            selected: null,
            sense: 0
            },
         {
            question: 'What is the biggest continent?',
            answer: [
                'Oceania',
                'Europe',
                'Asia',
                'Africa'
            ],
            correct_answer: 2,
            selected: null,
            sense: 0
            }
        ],
  }},
  
  methods: {
    backBtn:function () {
      if (this.question > 0) {
        this.question = this.question - 1;
      }
    },
    nextBtn: function(){
      this.answered < this.questions.length ? this.answered++ : ''; 
     if(!nextBtn.hasAttribute('disabled') && this.currentQuestion < (questionsLength -1)) {    
        this.currentQuestion++; //I think error happen here
        
        answers.forEach(answer => {
          answer.classList.contains('selected') ? answer.classList.remove('selected') : '';
        });
    nextBtn.setAttribute('disabled', '');   
      } 
      else if(this.currentQuestion >= (questionsLength -1)) {
        
        this.questions.forEach( (question) => {
          if(question.selected == question.correct_answer && question.sense ==0) {
            
            this.correctAnswers++;
            question.sense = 1;
            
          } else if(question.selected != question.correct_answer && question.sense ==0) {
            
            this.wrongAnswers++;
            question.sense = 1;
            let temp = {};
            temp.answers = question.answers;
            temp.question = question.question;
            temp.correct_answer = question.correct_answer;
            temp.selected = question.selected;
            
            this.wrongQuestions.push(temp);
          }
        });
    result.classList.add('active');
        question.classList.add('blur');
      } 
    },
   
     calculateResult: (questions) => {
      var correct;
      for(var i=0; i< questions.length; i++) {
        this.questions[i].selected == questions[i].correct ?  correct++ : '';
      }
return (correct / questions.length) * 100;
    },
    selectAnswer: function(a) {
      var choice = a.currentTarget,
          answers = document.querySelectorAll('.answers span'),
          nextBtn = document.querySelector('.next-btn');
      
      answers.forEach(answer => {
        answer.classList.contains('selected') ? answer.classList.remove('selected') : '';
      });
      
      choice.classList.add('selected');
      
      this.questions[this.currentQuestion].selected = choice.dataset.index;
 nextBtn.removeAttribute('disabled');
      
    },
  },       
  mounted() {
    var nextBtn = this.$el.querySelector('.next-btn'),
        wrongAnswersBtn = this.$el.querySelector('.show-wrong-ones'),
        backBtn = this.$el.querySelector('.back-Btn'),
        answers = this.$el.querySelectorAll('.answers span'),
        questionsLength = this.questions.length,
        result = this.$el.querySelector('.result'),
        question = this.$el.querySelector('.question'),
        closeResult = this.$el.querySelector('.result button.close'),
        wrongQuestions = this.$el.querySelector('.wrong-questions'),
        showMyResults = this.$el.querySelector('#return-to-result'); 
 
    
},
  template: '<div><div v-if="counter < questions.length"> <h2>{{questions[currentQuestion].question }}</h2></br> <span class=answer v-for="(answer, index) in questions[currentQuestion].answer" :key="index" v-bind:data-index="index" @click="selectAnswer">{{ answer }}</span><p><button class="backBtn" v-on:click="backBtn">BACK</button> <button class="next-btn" v-on:click="nextBtn" disabled > {{ currentQuestion < (questions.length -1) ? "Next" : "Result!" }} </button></p> </div> <div class="result"><div class="success"></div></div></div>',
})
var test1 = new Vue({
  el: "#app1",
  data: {
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what's undefined is not the `nextBtn` method, but the `nextBtn` variable that you referenced inside the `nextBtn` method (from this line `if(!nextBtn.hasAttribute('disabled') && this.currentQuestion < (questionsLength -1)) {`), on `mounted` you initialized some variables, you should declare those variables first on `data()`, then initialize in the `mounted`. When you're accessing the data, you should use `this` like `this.nextBtn`, also try to change the name of the variables so that they're not the same as the name of the method (e.g. in here you have `nextBtn` as a function and `nextBtn` as a variable).